# Selecting different templates for a Plone tile

Tags: plone

on Plone, tiles are nothing but Zope browser views; we were wondering if it is possible to declare/use different templates for a tile on an simple way.

according to [plone.tiles](https://github.com/plone/plone.tiles) documentation you can override a template for a different context.

```
<plone:tile
    name="sample.persistenttile"
    template="override.pt"
    permission="zope.Public"
    for="*"
    layer=".interfaces.IMyLayer"
    />
```

should we need to implement a way to mark the tiles with some interface for this? is there a different/easier solution?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with specifying the template in ZCML like you did in the question? Are you trying to use different templates for the same tile based on some condition?

Comment: yes; think of the way we select views for objects on the Plone interface; I want to select a template for a tile the same way; something like that will solve my use case.